# Is there any way of accessing internal abstract operations in ES6 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, abstract

The ES6 specification states that [abstract operations](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-operations) are not part of the language, but they are used internally. Some of these operations, such as [CreateHTML](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createhtml) look generally useful... Is there really no way of accessing them? No deep prototype hackery to get at these functions?

Comment: Probably "Other, more specialized abstract operations are defined throughout this specification." are better for your specific needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one is describing the semantics of a programming language / API it is really important to get everything right and non-ambiguous. Imagine now that you are describing how should `String.prototype.fontcolor(color)` work. That's part of the API that you need define so you must be rigorous about it and you start listing requirements:

1. If the string is empty, then...
2. If the color is empty, then...
3. If the color is not a valid color, then...
4. ...

Now if you have repeating requirements for multiple functions, then you can generalize those requirements and just tell whoever's implementing the standard to apply the requirements to some other function (e.g. *'Requirements 1 and 2 also hold for `String.prototype.fontsize`'*). Instead of just saying 'Requirements 1 and 2 also hold for...' you can define the public API operations using an **abstract operation** e.g. *'Call RequirementsForStringPrototypeAcceptingOneArgument and exit if it returns false'* where *RequirementsForStringPrototypeAcceptingOneArgument* contains req. 1 and 2.

Note that those requirements themselves are not part of the API. There aren't designed to be and there's no need for them to be - there are just a tool for avoiding repetition in the standard. The implementation may really choose to have a `CreateHTML` function somewhere but it may as well just put a bunch of `if` statements if they deem it better. Thus, no, there's no way to access these operations as

1. The implementation may not have such a function in the first place.
2. There's no reason for the implementation to expose them.
3. Even if they did expose some helper internal function, they have no reason to expose it with the name mentioned in the standard or have it do the exact same thing as in the standard - it's all internal details to the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer! The reality you describe leads me to conclude the spec is a little weak. The set of functions based on the CreateHTML abstract is limited (perhaps rightly so) and some are not useful, like the ancient blink(). Just recently I coded my own generic function for wrapping content in HTML tags; surely a native solution would have been better. Anyhow, this is an aside - thanks again.

Comment: @Theod'Or All the string methods that create html strings are ancient and deprecated. They're listed in Annex B, which exists solely as a recommendation on how to ensure web compatibility.

Comment: @Bergi I know, but I was being cautious in case someone jumps on me for saying fontColor() or any of the others is not useful when they still can be used in HTML 4. I think the deprecation of these functions only makes the case for a generic CreateHTML() stronger.

Comment: @Theod'Or The reason that they are deprecated in ECMAScript is because they don't fit into the *language*. They might be useful in certain environments, but not everywhere - they shouldn't be part of a general-purpose language string interface. (Some environments still provide native functions for this purpose, e.g. the DOM API in any browser). However, this is specific to `CreateHTML`, what other internals did you have in mind?